# Izpack. Cannot find named resource: 'info'

Tags: java, maven, java-web-start, izpack

I have built executable .jar file with izpack-maven-plugin.
If i run it like:
java -jar install.jar -everything is okay.
But if I run it using JWS i have got an error message:

```
Can't load log handler "com.izforge.izpack.util.LogHandler"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.izforge.izpack.util.LogHandler
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.izforge.izpack.util.LogHandler

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.izforge.izpack.api.exception.IzPackException: com.izforge.izpack.api.exception.ContainerException: com.izforge.izpack.api.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Cannot find named resource: 'info'
    at com.izforge.izpack.installer.bootstrap.InstallerGui$1.run(InstallerGui.java:64)

Caused by: com.izforge.izpack.api.exception.ContainerException: com.izforge.izpack.api.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Cannot find named resource: 'info'

Caused by: com.izforge.izpack.api.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Cannot find named resource: 'info'
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: does the install.jar make reference to other jars within it's manifest? if that's the case then you would need to put them into the jnlp file and make them available for download

Comment: it's packed in install.jar/resources. i think it's izpack resources.

Comment: The same thing is happening to me. But I have no idea what is causing it.